# かどうか after a negated predicate

Tags: grammar, nuances

> 稲が病気になってい**ないかどうか**いつもチェックして...
>   Always check whether or not your rice plants are diseased and ...

This is the first time I've seen かどうか come after a negated predicate. Is this usual? How does the meaning/nuance change if I just say なっているかどうか?

Comment: +1 Great question. I think the sense here is to *confirm that the rice plants are* **not** *diseased*.  Farmers don't want to find diseased plants.  So, I would suspect that the wording is more to accord with what the farmers hope for.

Comment: How is that unusual? "Check if there is a new comment under the question." - "Check if there are no new comments under the question." Why would Japanese language be devoid of such constructions?

Comment: @A.Ellett Sounds convincing. Could you put that in an answer so I can close the question off. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this usage of ないか is very common.

病気になっていないかどうか implies the speaker is expecting the ～ない pattern (病気になっていない is what the speaker is expecting). 病気になっているかどうか is neutral, but it can imply the speaker is expecting the positive pattern (病気になっている), depending on the context.

> - 宿題をやったか聞いた。: natural
> - 宿題をやっていないか聞いた。: odd
> - 宿題をやり忘れたか聞いた。: usually odd, okay when asking objectively
> - 宿題をやり忘れていないか聞いた。: natural